# Laravel 5.6 trying to assign a model's property with another model's property

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

So I have this following code:

```
foreach($goods as &$good) {
        $good->steps = collect([]);

        $starting_steps = Step::select('id', 'availability_id', 'route_id')->get();

        foreach($starting_steps as $step) {
            $final_steps = Step::select('id', 'availability_id', 'route_id')                    ->where('availability_id', $step->availability_id)
                ->where('status', 'active')
                ->where('route_id', $step->route_id)
                ->where('id', '>', $step->id)
                ->limit(1)->get();

            if($final_steps->count()) {
                if($good->steps->isEmpty()) {
                    $good->steps = $final_steps;
                }
                else {
                    $good->steps->push($final_steps);
                }
            }
        }

        if($good->steps->count()) {
            foreach($good->steps as $step) {
                $leg = new Availabilities_goods_leg;
                $leg->availability_id = $step->availability_id;
                $leg->route_id = $step->route_id;
                $leg->good_id = $good->id;
                $leg->match = 1;
                $leg->save();
            }
        }
    }
```

at this line `$leg->availability_id = $step->availability_id;` I am trying to save the `availability_id` contained in `$step->availability_id` but I get the following error `Property [availability_id] does not exist on this collection instance.`

If I put `$leg->availability_id = 4` then everything works fine, no error. 
Only when I try to assign it with `$step->availability_id` it get the error.
I tried to see if `$step->availability_id` has any value by doing `dd($step->availability_id)` and it has.
What could be wrong there?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the error, for some reason, if I change `if($good->steps->isEmpty())` with `if(isset($good->steps))` it works.
Maybe somebody find this useful.

Comment: do you know why your solution works??? if you don't know, i am ready to give an answer and get votes :P

Answer (score 0):

[isset official doc](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

isset() core php function which check if a variable exists or doesn't exist that means null.
and laravels collection method checks a given collection does have elements within it or not.
[isEmpty laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-isempty)

null->isEmpty() doesn't stop php from throwing the error, while isset() does